# How can I disable sampling in Azure Application Insights with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I've read the azure documents (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling). There are examples with .Net and Java and also Javascript for client. But could not see a example for node.js (backend).

How can I disable sampling in Azure Application Insights with Node.js (backend)

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#sampling) you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#sampling):

**By default, the SDK will send all collected data to the Application Insights service.**

So the sampling is disabled by default.

And you can also use the following code to disable/enable sampling by setting samplingPercentage to 0 or non-zero value, like below:

```
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("<instrumentation_key>");
appInsights.defaultClient.config.samplingPercentage = 33; // 33% of all telemetry will be sent to Application Insights
appInsights.start();
```